# How to automate labelling

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a csv file(sentences.csv) that contains lists of sentences, and i wanted to automatically label sentences that have both verbs, especially/but not only; (will cause, getting, can lead to, increases the risk of, leading cause of, it caused, it causes, cause of, most likely to), and also diseases list from a csv file called diseases2.csv, to label 1 if exist, else label 0 in a new column of the csv file itself.

Below are some of the codes i have so far

```
import csv
import pandas as pd


file=pd.read_csv("sentences.csv")
diseases =pd.read_csv("diseases2.csv")


pattern= '|'.join(diseases['Lists'])


file["useful/unuseful"] = np.where(file["STORY"].str.contains(pattern, na=False),1, 0)


file.to_csv("sentences.csv")
```

These are the example sentences in the sentences.csv (the one in italic is the verb, and in bold is the diseases)

```
STORY
Overeating is the leading cause of obesity
-It is also found that men are more likely to experience heart attacks than women
-Heart attacks are also the second cause of death among cardiovascular diseases.
-According to a statistics released by the Ministry of Health, cardiovascular diseases are the second leading cause of death in UK after cancer.
-A talk about heart attack is presented by Doctor Lee
```

The code should produce these results in sentences.csv

```
STORY                                                                                   useful/unuseful
Overeating is the leading cause of obesity                                                1
It is also found that men are more likely to experience heart attacks than women          1
Heart attacks are also the second cause of death among cardiovascular diseases.           1
According to a statistics released by the Ministry of Health, cardiovascular diseases     1
are the second leading cause of death in UK after cancer.
A talk about heart attack is presented by Doctor Lee                                      0
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote something like this and it worked. In this code i get words from `check_list` so in your case you can get `check_list` with `diseases['Lists'].values.tolist()` and other strings.

```
data['STORY'] = data['STORY'].str.replace('*', '#') # Need this because '*' is special character for regex. Its just temporary.

check_list = ['obesity', 'heart attacks', 'death', 'cause of']  # list of strings that will change label

def is_contains(df, check_list):
    for check in check_list:
        first_check = f'#{check}#'
        second_check = f'##{check}##'
        df.loc[df['STORY'].str.contains(str(first_check)) == True, 'useful/unuseful'] = 1
        df.loc[df['STORY'].str.contains(str(second_check)) == True, 'useful/unuseful'] = 1
    df['useful/unuseful'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
    df['useful/unuseful'] = df['useful/unuseful'].astype(int)
    df['STORY'] = data['STORY'].str.replace('#', '*')

is_contains(data, check_list)
```

Output is:

```
                                               STORY  useful/unuseful
0   Overeating is the *leading cause of* **obesity**                1
1  -It is also found that men are more likely *to...                1
2  -Heart attacks are also the second *cause of* ...                1
3  -According to a statistics released by the Min...                0
4  -A talk about heart attack is presented by Doc...                0
```

Comment: omg, actually those asterisk is italic and bold, to indicate that the one in italic is verb and the one in bold is the diseases, i should've double check my question before posting